# HTML <a> tag attribute

Tags: html, xhtml, tags

I am needing to attach a value to an `<a>` element that will be handled in jQuery.  Basically, I am aware of the `data-` attribute prepended to whatever name I want to give it, but I'm not sure this is the best for (X)HTML, as the software I am coding for is declaring DTD's within the  tag, so it would not pass (X)HTML 5.0 validation, as I'm not able to change this to exclude the DTD's.

My question is, can I just use the `<a>` elements `tag` attribute to hold the URL links that jQuery will grab using the following code: `$(this).attr('tag');`  The href attributes value is set to:  `javascript:void(0);` because the actual URL triggers an AJAX event and is not an actual page that one should be browsing to in their browser, as it just performs an action to be taken when clicked on.

I'm not entirely sure what the `<a>` elements `tag` attribute is to be used for, but am wondering if this is the best known attribute to use to be able to be valid (X)HTML in both HTML 4 and 5?

Comment: Why are you so worried about any tag doesn't validate in HTML4 ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga  Because the software is using DTD's and `data-` attributes give me an error when validating XHTML for HTML 4, and in HTML 5 validation, it gives me an error on the <!DOCTYPE> because it has DTD's in it.  And I'm not talking about any tag, I am talking about adding a value to the `tag` attribute of the `<a>` element.

Comment: Why not just implement a custom DTD? http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/

Comment: Where did you find the tag attribute mentioned?

Comment: What do you mean by “declaring DTD’s within the tag”? You cannot declare Document Type Definitions inside tags. Please provide an example that illustrates what you are really doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, can I just use the `<a>` elements `tag` attribute

There is no tag attribute in HTML. So that will have all the problems of `data-*` but without the future support.

If you want to store arbitrary data in HTML 4/XHTML 1 then the best attribute to use is probably `class`.

> The href attributes value is set to: `javascript:void(0);` because the actual URL triggers an AJAX event

Don't do that. Use a real (working) URI, and add a JavaScript event handler that prevents the default behaviour if it succeeds. If the URI contains the data you need for your JS to run, then all the better as you can extract it from the `href` attribute.

Comment: I was just thinking about class, but holding an URL in class .. is somewhat weird..

Comment: Then hold the data in the href attribute.  If you don't care about graceful degradation (which is a reasonable approach for some problems) then use HREF as a data attribute, just make sure that you are preventing the default action with some script.

Comment: I am already using class, and I need to store an actual url link, which wouldn't be proper in the `class` attribute.  And ouch, I don't know why I thought that `tag` was an actual attribute available... argg!  There has to be a better way than using the `class` attribute.

Comment: Yes. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, used `event.preventDefault();` in jQuery and works like a charm!  SOLVED!